# Problems with downloading pdf files using Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to Python and am trying to download all the pdffiles from this website(https://www.americanrhetoric.com/barackobamaspeeches.htm)
But the problem is I cannot download any of the files.
I tried this code from geeksforgeeks(https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-scrape-all-pdf-files-in-a-website/) but it is not downloading files:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import io
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader
 
 
url = "https://www.americanrhetoric.com/barackobamaspeeches.htm"
read = requests.get(url)
html_content = read.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "html.parser")
 
list_of_pdf = set()
l = soup.find('p')
p = l.find_all('a')
 
for link in (p):
    pdf_link = (link.get('href')[:-5]) + ".pdf"
    print(pdf_link)
    list_of_pdf.add(pdf_link)
 
def info(pdf_path):
    response = requests.get(pdf_path)
     
    with io.BytesIO(response.content) as f:
        pdf = PdfFileReader(f)
        information = pdf.getDocumentInfo()
        number_of_pages = pdf.getNumPages()
 
    txt = f"""
    Information about {pdf_path}:
 
    Author: {information.author}
    Creator: {information.creator}
    Producer: {information.producer}
    Subject: {information.subject}
    Title: {information.title}
    Number of pages: {number_of_pages}
    """
    print(txt)
    return information
 
 
for i in list_of_pdf:
    info(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `User-Agent` in  `headers` so you get html code of website

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.americanrhetoric.com/barackobamaspeeches.htm"
headers={"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.127 Safari/537.36"}
read = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
html_content = read.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "html.parser")
```

Now find all `a` tag from `table` tag find `URL` iterating through list and make request to end url to get content of PDF and you can write to particular folder

```
hrefs=soup.find("table",attrs={"id":"AutoNumber1"}).find_all("a")


main_link="https://www.americanrhetoric.com"
for ref in hrefs:
    if ref['href'].endswith(".pdf"):
        url=main_link+"/"+ref['href']
        with open(r"temp"+"\\"+url.split("/")[-1].replace("%20",""),"wb") as data:
            r=requests.get(url)
            data.write(r.content)
```